# Terraform: Collecting lists of maps from an object

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to return a list of maps from a Terraform module. However, instead of returning a list of maps as expected, I'm getting a tuple with 1 element.

```
locals {

  requestors = [var.assignment_policies[*].requestor_settings.requestor]

}
```

I expect it to return a list of maps, but I get a list of tuple instead.

The return I'm getting is `local.requestors is list of tuple with 1 element`.

Below is the object I'm iterating through:

```
assignment_policies = [
    {
      display_name     = "Initial Policy"
      description      = "Initial Policy"
      duration_in_days = 365


      requestor_settings = {
        scope_type = "SpecificDirectorySubjects"
        requestor = [
          {
            object_id    = "test-grp-3"
            subject_type = "groupMembers"
          },
          {
            object_id    = "example@example.com"
            subject_type = "singleUser"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
]
```

Comment: " misbehaving oddly" - what does it mean? Your question is unclear and lacks details.

Comment: By misbehaving oddly, I mean that it's returning a "list of tuples" instead of a "list of maps" as I'd expect. I'm looking for a way to return a list of maps here.

Comment: So what exactly is the expected value of `requestors`?

Comment: it should be simply: [{object_id = "test-grp-3" subject_type = "groupMembers"},{object_id = "example@example.com" subject_type = "singleUser"}].

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [flatten](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/flatten) to make list of maps:

```
locals {
 requestors = flatten(var.assignment_policies[*].requestor_settings.requestor)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This definitely helps. Terraform is now reading a tuple with the correct number of elements. However, it's still reading a tuple instead of a list of maps. Do you know how to convert this tuple into a list of maps?

Comment: @JosephLeiber You question does not provide any information about "reading a tuple", no errors, no context. Please make new question with relevant TF code and error messages.

Comment: thank you so much for your help here. I'm having a lot of trouble debugging this because it's difficult to print the output from Terraform code. I'm used to doing this with Python print() statements, but I feel like I'm flying blind with Terraform.

Comment: I posted a new question here based on your advice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76902990/terraform-converting-a-tuple-into-a-list-of-maps

Comment: thanks for the help here! Flatten did the trick perfectly :)

Comment: @JosephLeiber Good. I asked as you didn't accept the answer, so I didn't know if it worked or not.