# Converting a tuple into a list of maps

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to create a list of maps so that I can perform a `lookup()` in my module. In the code below, `local.requestors` should return a list of maps. However, what I end up with is `local.requestors is a tuple with 2 elements`. How can I convert this tuple into a list of maps?

```
locals {

  requestors = flatten([var.assignment_policies[*].requestor_settings.requestor])

}

assignment_policies = [
    {
      requestor_settings = {
        scope_type = "SpecificDirectorySubjects"
        requestor = [
          {
            object_id    = "test-grp-3"
            subject_type = "groupMembers"
          },
          {
            object_id    = "example@example.com"
            subject_type = "singleUser"
          }
        ]
      }
    } ]
```

What I need to return and perform a `lookup()` on:

```
requestors = [
     {
       object_id    = "test-grp-3"
       subject_type = "groupMembers"
     },
     {
       object_id    = "example@example.com"
       subject_type = "singleUser"
     }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using a [for expression](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/for) to iterate over the assignment_policies:

```
locals {
  assignment_policies = [
    {
      requestor_settings = {
        scope_type = "SpecificDirectorySubjects"
        requestor = [
          {
            object_id    = "test-grp-3"
            subject_type = "groupMembers"
          },
          {
            object_id    = "example@example.com"
            subject_type = "singleUser"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      requestor_settings = {
        scope_type = "newscope"
        requestor = [
          {
            object_id    = "foo"
            subject_type = "bar"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]

  requestors = flatten([for policy in local.assignment_policies : policy.requestor_settings.requestor])
}

output "requestors" {
  value = local.requestors

}
```

This outputs:

```
Changes to Outputs:
  + requestors = [
      + {
          + object_id    = "test-grp-3"
          + subject_type = "groupMembers"
        },
      + {
          + object_id    = "example@example.com"
          + subject_type = "singleUser"
        },
      + {
          + object_id    = "foo"
          + subject_type = "bar"
        },
    ]
```